# "Debugging connection was closed: Render process was gone", when trying to download a 7gb from cdn

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

We are trying to download a 7 GB from CDN using JSZip.js. The chrome browser suddenly seems to close the connection when the download reaches 3.5gb every time. The approximate time is around 15 mins. Is there a way we increase the tolerant time to 1 hr say?

$("#downloadJSZip").on('click', function () {

```
var result = [{ "cdn": "url....", "filename": "7.84 gb.zip", "size": 4194304, "path": "7.84 gb" }];
var Promise = window.Promise;
                        if (!Promise) {
                            Promise = JSZip.external.Promise;
                        }


                        function urlToPromise(url) {
                            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                                JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
                                    if(err) {
                                        reject(err);
                                    } else {
                                        resolve(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }


                        var fileNameArray = [];

                        function changeFileName(fileName,j){
                            var i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
                            var newfilename = fileName.slice(0,i)+"--"+j+fileName.slice(i);

                            if(fileNameArray.indexOf(newfilename) != -1){
                                j = j+1;
                                changeFileName(fileName,j);
                            }
                            return newfilename;
                        }


                        var zip = new JSZip();
                            // find every checked item
                            result.forEach(function(file){
                                var filename = file.filename;
                                if(fileNameArray.indexOf(filename) != -1){
                                    var newfilename = changeFileName(filename,1);
                                    filename = newfilename;
                                }
                                fileNameArray.push(filename);
                                var url = file.cdn;
                                var folder = (file.path);
                                zip.folder(folder).file(filename, urlToPromise(url), {binary:true});
                                // zip.file(filename, urlToPromise(url), {binary:true});

                            });

                            // when everything has been downloaded, we can trigger the dl
                            zip.generateAsync({type:"blob",
                                }, function updateCallback(metadata) {
                                var msg = "progression : " + metadata.percent.toFixed(2) + " %";
                                if(metadata.currentFile) {
                                    msg += ", current file = " + metadata.currentFile;
                                }

                                console.log(msg);
                                console.log(metadata.percent|0);
                            })
                            .then(function callback(blob) {

                                // see FileSaver.js
                                //console.log("blob=====>");
                                //console.dir(blob);
                                //saveAs(blob, "example.zip") ;
                                saveAs(blob, $scope.folderName+".zip") ;

                                //console.log("done !");


                            }, function (e) {


                            });
```

});

Is this chrome browser configuration?

Comment: Chrome has a hardcoded memory limit for a tab process which is about 3.5GB even in 64-bit Chrome. This is done to prevent a bad page script from exhausting all the system memory. As for a solution, try FileSystem API, which is available in Chrome, to download the data to a temporary disk file directly.

Comment: Can you share a sample api by using filesystem? As per this post https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ there is no support for filesystem api. We want to zip and download a large file onto to users disk (if possible to do the zip process also on disc instead of process memory). Possibly using all the browser types

Comment: Like I said it's Chrome only, and yes Chrome may remove it in the future, but right now it works. I don't have an example but you should be able to find those yourself.

Comment: The site https://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi suggests that api support is going to continue..